# implementation of collapsing tableView Cells

Tags: iphone, animation, tableview, cell

so I wanted to have a table with multiple sections and each one with multiple cells. By touching a section's header, this section should expand and the others should minimize, leaving only the header visible.

I looked up some suggestions and accomplished this by a) setting the cell's height to 0 and reloding the data animated and b) adding a button as a subview to the cell's header.

Anyway, while it works fine, mainly, there is minor problem, namely, I can see a 'flickering' below each cell's header, when the change is animated. I guess its because the cell's content is redrawn. And I don't like it!

I wanted to ask whether the approach is correct or generally your opinion about it. Moreover I would be really happy, if someone could hint me why the 'flickering' appears in my table :)

EDIT: Another thing is, that if I press on a section, it appears like all the section headers are pressed.... maybe someone has seen this weird artifact also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove cells instead of setting height to 0.
You will have less call to data source and delegate and no more artifacts.

Comment: I like that! Worked well for me. Any ideas, why that visual stuff occurred before? And why it seemed like all buttons were pressed?